# createSelector with typescript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, reselect

I have a very simple selector from `reselect` library:

```
const getUsers = (state: State): User[] => state.users;

type ExtendedUser = User & { role: string };

const userRoleSelector = createSelector(
  getUsers,
  (users: User[]): ExtendedUser[] => users.map((user) => ({ ...user, role: "basic" })),
);
```

I wanted to use it with typescript generics built in for `createSelector`:

```
export function createSelector<S, R1, T>(
  selector: Selector<S, R1>,
  combiner: (res: R1) => T
): OutputSelector<S, T, (res: R1) => T>

export function createSelector<S, P, R1, T>(
   selector: ParametricSelector<S, P, R1>,
  combiner: (res: R1) => T
): OutputParametricSelector<S, P, T, (res: R1) => T>
```

So I used it as:

```
const userRoleSelector = createSelector<State>(...);
                                        ^^^^ error (expected minimum 3 type arguments)
```

### Question

> What should I place in `<>` ? Thanks!

Comment: it should be <State, User[], ExtendedUser[]>